# PowerApps: Unable to Filter/Search DataTable on a choice SharePoint column

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-formula, powerapps-canvas

I have SharePoint list I'm viewing in a PowerApps screen using the DataTable control. I need to filter down the rows based on if one of the fields (happens to be a choice of string values) has a certain value.

[image]

I have a drop-down control (Dropdown1) that has all the choices for that field. Its items property is "Choices('SD Fast'.Progress)".

[image]

Here is the expression that is used as the source (Items property) for the DataTable control:

```
Search('SD Fast', Text(Dropdown1.SelectedText.Value), "Progress")
```

I'm getting an error message on this expression: "The function search has some invalid arguments".

[image]

If I change the search to look at a plain text column, it works fine.

Please advise. Thanks, guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the expression that solved the problem:

```
Filter('SD Fast', Dropdown1.SelectedText.Value in Progress.Value)
```

I needed to use the "in" operator and also reference the Value property of that field.